# Store in the database from twig Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to now if there is a way to store in my database somes values displayed on twig ? the values was calculated with javascript/jason, and i dont want to do the same script on symfony or php ...

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other interaction with the client you must :

- send a request to your symfony application
- make a controller that can work on this request
- make this controller store the data you sent within the request

For that two possibilities :

- Use XHR to let Javascript send this request
- Use javascript to fill a HTML form and let the user submit this form